# SVG with references, multiple loads

Tags: html, css, apache, svg

i'm creating a whole set of world flags in SVG, uniting all their common styles (For example, 3 vertical bands, or 3 horizontal stripes).

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 750 450">
<style>
    rect, line { shape-rendering: crispEdges; }
    svg .f { display: none }
    svg .f:target { display: inline }
</style>
<defs>
<rect id="f31" width="750" height="150"  x="0" y="0" />
<rect id="f32" width="750" height="150"  x="0" y="150" />
<rect id="f33" width="750" height="150"  x="0" y="300" />
</defs>
<svg>
  <svg><g id="am" name="armenia" class="f"><use xlink:href="#f31" fill="#ff0000"/><use xlink:href="#f32" fill="#00f"/><use xlink:href="#f33" fill="#ffa500"/></g></svg>
  <svg><g id="at" name="austria" class="f"><use xlink:href="#f31" fill="#df0000"/><use xlink:href="#f32" fill="#fff"/><use xlink:href="#f33" fill="#df0000"/></g></svg>
  <svg><g id="gm" name="gambia" class="f"><use xlink:href="#f31" fill="#ff0000"/><use xlink:href="#f32" fill="#fff"/><use xlink:href="#f53" fill="#009"/><use xlink:href="#f33" fill="#090"/></g></svg>
</svg>
```

Then I call this SVG from CSS (You can do it on HTML directly too, with <img src="flags.svg#am" />

```
.wf-am{background-image:url(../svg/isoflags.svg#am)}
.wf-at{background-image:url(../svg/isoflags.svg#at)}
.wf-gm{background-image:url(../svg/isoflags.svg#gm)}
```

However, instead of having less load, it creates more. Every #am or #gm requests isoflags.svg again and again. With 250 flags, it boggles the whole thing down to 12 seconds to load. I'm doing this so i do NOT have to request 250 files, but it's really being a pain in the *** to make it work. Any ideas of what I could do differently?